# if greater than matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I have a matrix of two columns and six rows, and want to build a second one with the following code:

```
 for i=2
if F(:,i)<50
G(:,i) = 1
end
end
```

But nothing happens...

The idea was that if a value in the second column in F was less than 50, then the corresponding value in G would be 1.

Sorry for probably basic question, but no idea why this doesn't work. If I change to evaluate whether the F value `~= 50`, then everything works as it should.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `if` statement is only executed once - not once per element. While `F(:,i)<50` returns an array of values, the `if` is either true or false; consequently, the next line is only executed once (either on all elements in G(:,i), or none of them).

For example, see this piece of code:

```
if(1 < [0 1 2]), disp('true'); end
```

It will produce no output, even though it is true for the third element. On the other hand,

```
if(1 < [2 3 4]), disp('true'); end
```

does produce output...

In general, the following:

```
1 < [0 1 2]
```

produces

```
0 0 1
```

Not sure why you say it doesn't work for `<` but it does work for `~=`. Maybe there are no elements equal to 50, so it only "seems" to work?

In general, there is a better way to do what you want, with a single line:

```
G(F(:,2)<50,2)=1
```

This uses "logical indexing", and is much faster than looping. It will consider each element of F(:,2), and modify the corresponding element in G.

One final comment: it is not great practice to use the variable `i` since it has a built in value of `sqrt(-1)`. If you have code anywhere that relies on it having that value, then accidentally overwriting it with any other value would break that. It's not the problem with your code today - but why set yourself up for a problem in the future.

Comment: +1 I always like explanations on logical statements. They are easy to get wrong.